# Website deployment to AWS issues with domain

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, virtualenv, zappa

When I attempt to certify a Domain using I am getting this error:

```
zappa certify

BadRequestException: An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the CreateDomainName operation: The domain name you provided already exists.
```

I have recently transferred this domain from GoDaddy to AWS.

Does anyone know a solution to this issue?

Comment: NS server updates can take up to two days, have you flushed your cached and does a dig for your domain return the name servers of your route53 domain. dig @8.8.8.8 +short NS yourdomain.com