# Zappa Certify Issue

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-route53, zappa

I've been having issues with deploying a domain I recently transferred from godaddy to AWS.

Here's the zappa settings:

```
{
"staging": {
    "app_function": "__init__.app",
    "aws_region": "ap-southeast-2",
    "profile_name": "default",
    "s3_bucket": "zappa-flowersapp",
    "domain": "minnidesign.com",
    "certificate_arn": "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:985294012425:certificate/a8740ef0-0d99-4355-ac99-210ead89b743"
    }
}
```

On running zappa certify the first time I get this error:

```
params[name] = orig_value.split('/')[-1]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

The second time I am getting this error:

```
raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
BadRequestException: An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the CreateDomainName operation: The domain name you provided already exists.
```

I have no idea why this is happening, I have never had this kind of issue with Zappa. (When I go to minnidesign.com there is a server not found error).

Does anyone know a solution to this problem? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Website deployment to AWS issues with domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47216585/website-deployment-to-aws-issues-with-domain)

Answer (score 0):

I just had to create a hosted zone then update the NS records of the registered domain with the new hosted zone's NS records, then created new certificate and worked a charm!

Comment: Could you spell out the steps a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Zappa fails with certify sometimes.

You can enter the apigateway dashboard on AWS and manually delete the entry before trying again.

```
AWS Console > apigateway > custom domain names > delete
```